# How to correctly use form_open() in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I use form_open() helper function in codeigniter, the resultant form action is http://[::1]/example.com. As you can see, having [::1] in my form action url is not directed to the controller method. I have already loaded helper from my controller. Please let us know if I am missing anything here. Thanks.

```
<?php echo form_open("auth/login");?>
<p>
<?php echo lang('login_identity_label', 'identity');?>
<?php echo form_input($identity);?>
</p>

 <p>
  <?php echo lang('login_password_label', 'password');?>
  <?php echo form_input($password);?>
 </p>

<p>
 <?php echo lang('login_remember_label', 'remember');?>
<?php echo form_checkbox('remember', '1', FALSE, 'id="remember"');?>
</p>
<p><?php echo form_submit('submit', lang('login_submit_btn'));?></p>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: Please put your code as well

Comment: I edited the question to add code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `base_url()` helper function:

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url()."auth/login");?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found the issue in my config file. $config['base_url'] was not set. After setting that it works.